# Shell script to delete files smaller than xMB with condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, rm

I'm trying to write a script to delete the smallest file if inside the folder has more than one file smaller than 10MB, but I did not succeed.

In my attempt

`find . -type f -size -10M -exec rm {} +`

Remove all less than 10 Mb, I need to remove only the smallest if inside the folder have 2 files smaller than 10MB recursively.

Any can help-me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to loop through the output of `find` and then keep track of then number of files and keep track of the smallest file, so at the end you can remove it:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/path/to/dir # replace here with your path

while read -d '' -r dir;do

    files_count=0
    unset min
    unset smallest_file

    while read -d '' -r file;do

            let files_count++
            min_size="$(du -b "${file}"|cut -f1)"
            min=${min:-"$min_size"}
            smallest_file=${smallest_file:-"$file"}

            if (( min_size < min ));then
                    min=$min_size
                    smallest_file=$file
            fi

    done < <(find "${dir}" -type f -size -10M -maxdepth 1 -print0)

    if (( files_count >= 2 ));then

            echo "$smallest_file"
            #rm -v "$smallest_file"

    fi

done < <(find "${path}" -type d -print0)
```

Comment: So, don't work here:
`find: 'smallest': No such file or directory`

From what I understand, it will remove the smallest of them all. But I need to delete only the smallest of the folder if there are >= 2 files with size under 10MB inside this folder.

Comment: @YagoLima Sorry, that was my test directory, replace with your directory path, I edited the code.

Comment: My bad, already changed here. But, like I said, it's showing only the smallest of them. I need the smallest file in the folder if within that folder there are >= 2 files smaller than 10MB.

Comment: @YagoLima I think I understood you now. Is the same script just wrap everything inside another while loop that traverse all directories and do what we did before for each directory. Notice the `maxdepth` option in the inner `find`.